# Special characters not showing for plain HTML text

Tags: php, html, special-characters, decode, iso

I a displaying in a website 2 types of text:

- One coming from PHP (either reading from SQL or simply hardcoded)
- Plain HTML written text

In order to display some Spanish special characters properly, I added the following:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
```

However, now the HTML text does not display the special characters well.
The Spanish ñ is showing Ã±.

Any solution to comply with both PHP and HTML?

Thanks

Comment: are you sure you want to use `ISO-8859-1`? use utf-8

Comment: You need to make sure the text coming from the database and your HTML source code are the same encoding. At the moment you seem to be mixing encodings. See the duplicate and/or [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/).